# Why anova table disappear when we use robust regression

Tags: regression, anova, robust

My question is When we run ols regression anova table is given and when we run robust regression then anova table disappear and adjusted r square is also not given why? I want to know the logic behind it and by ANOVA I mean analysis of variance.

Comment: What software and packages do you use to run these analyses?

Comment: I am using stata

Comment: Actually I want to know the difference between ols regression and robust regression with logics